# deploying and running embedded mule in webapp (Mule twitter integration)

Tags: maven, twitter, esb, mule

Hi I am newbaby to Mule!! 
 I want to run this simple app (receives input from url and post to my twitter account using twitter connector). 
I try first deploying it on CloudHub and it works http://twitterconnector.cloudhub.io/addtweet?mymessage=firsttweet
after that I wanted to try deploying on Tomcat so I created simple webapp using maven and put all required dependences for Mule in pom.xml, set web.xml and mule-config.xml files  and when I go to localhost:8181/easymule-test/services/addtweet?mymessage=firsttweet it is not working!

Can someone pls help/explain what is the problem? 
than you in advance!! 
Here is the flow:

```
  <flow name="twitterconnectorFlow1" doc:name="twitterconnectorFlow1">
  <servlet:inbound-endpoint path="addtweet" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Servlet"/>
   <twitter:update-status config-ref="test_ECAccount" status="#[header:INBOUND:mymessage]" doc:name="Twitter Connector"/>
   <expression-transformer evaluator = "groovy" expression="payload.toString()" returnSourceIfNull="true" doc:name="Expression"/>
    </flow>
```

**Edit:** web.xml configuration fragment

```
   <web-app>
  <display-name>easymule-test</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.mule.config</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/muleconfig.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

   <listener>
        <listener-class>org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ajax</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.mule.transport.ajax.container.MuleAjaxServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>muleServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.mule.transport.servlet.MuleReceiverServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>muleResources</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.mule.transport.ajax.MuleJarResourcesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>muleServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>muleResources</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/mule-resource/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ajax</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ajax/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: can you share the error you are getting as well?

Comment: HTTP 404 resource not found on this path

Comment: Can you also show the bits of `web.xml` where you load and bootstrap Mule?

Comment: Hi David I edit question here is the my web.xml and updated Mule flow.

Comment: I run with similar parameters: the only difference in my config is that I load the configuration from the classpath not from `/WEB-INF`. But if that would fail, you would see Mule complaining about not being able to load `/WEB-INF/muleconfig.xml`: I assume that it loads fine.

Comment: Also can you update the flow configuration with the fix I suggested in my answer? Just to be sure we're on the same page.

Comment: which fix? you mean to put in web.xml <parm-value>classpath:muleconfig? Maybe its not problem the location of muleconfig file but multiple annotations found at this line:
 - listener-class references to non-existent class 
  "org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener"
 - <listener-class>org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener</listener I dont know how to fix it?

Comment: Also now I have error in MuleConfig.xml for multiple annotations Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Referenced file contains errors (http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/twitter/2.3/mule-twitter.xsd). For more information, 
  right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."...

Comment: The fix about the `inbound-endpoint path` attribute: it is still wrong in the above config.

Comment: What do you mean by "now I have error"? What have you changed? What is your exact Mule config currently?

Comment: Aha sorry I forgot to update... cause its Maven webapp project Eclipse didnt give me option Run on Server I guess its only recognise Dynamic Web Project so I had to manually deploy in Tomcat webapp... but I found out that if I add dynamic web module in Project facets I can Run on server. This is what I've changed... and now in web.xml and mulecofig.xml I have above errors.

Answer (score 1):

A servlet endpoint path is a path not an address, so use:

```
<servlet:inbound-endpoint path="sendtweet" ...
```

Assuming:

- your web-app is deployed on the `/easymule-test` context,
- and is running on port `8181`
- and the `org.mule.transport.servlet.MuleReceiverServlet` is bound to the `services` path

then you'll access the above endpoint at `http://localhost:8181/easymule-test/services/sendtweet`.

Comment: Thank you David I've changed it but it constantly gives me HTTP 404 resource is not available

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention the Mule servlet, sorry.

Comment: I still have 404 :( any suggestions? Thnak you in advance!!

Comment: Removing `servletUrl` from `servlet:connector`, I never set this attribute and it's working fine for me.